# How to send data from android phone in a XML file programatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a code to fetch inbox and show in ListAdapter and now i want save inbox data to a xml file i want communication with server, exactly send xml file to server. How?

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListAdapter.class));
        }
    List<SMSData> smsList2 = new ArrayList<SMSData>();

    Uri outuri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Cursor outc = getContentResolver()
            .query(outuri, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(outc);

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if (outc.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < outc.getCount(); i++) {
            SMSData sms = new SMSData();
            sms.setBody(outc.getString(outc.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                    .toString());
            sms.setNumber(outc.getString(
                    outc.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
            smsList2.add(sms);

            outc.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    outc.close();

    // Set smsList in the ListAdapter
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter2(this, smsList2));

}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: For what do you want to use XML. Just for saving data? Or for communication with server?

Comment: i want saving data in a xml file and communication with server, exactly send xml file to server

Answer (score 0):

If your xml-file will have simple content you can write it like simple text file. here is code draft

```
public void save() {
        String content = "<content>";
        for (SMS sms : smsList) {
            content += "<sms>";
            content += "<body>" + sms.getBody() + "</body>";
            content += "<number>" + sms.getNumber() + "</number>";
            content += "</sms>";
        }
        content += "</content>"

        // now we can send string to server or can save it
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(%path_where_you_want_to_save%));
        writer.write(content);
        writer.close();
    }
```

If your xml will have more complicated structure try to use serialization libraries. Like a [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php).
Good tutorial about simple you can find [here](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/10/23/android-and-xml-serialization-with-simple/)

P.S. If you can change server code I suggest you to use JSON format instead of XML. It's more simple. For saving data in JSON you can use google GSON library.

Comment: Nooo, i want save inbox in xml file and then how to send this file to server? i have 2 question: 1.how to save inbox in xml file? 2.how to send xml file to server? :(